# Image not upload properly as an image to AWS S3 in Next.js

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, next.js

In my next js app, I am trying to upload an image to aws s3. It was uploaded into AWS s3, but when I downloaded it, it is not an image. Not sure if the error because of my front-end or server side logic, I have included both files.

Here is my server side code in '/api/upload folder' to handle uploading to S3.

```
import { S3Client, PutObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

const s3Client = new S3Client({
region: "us-east-1",
credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY!,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AWS_S3_SECRET_KEY!,
},
});

async function handler(req:NextApiRequest, res:NextApiResponse) {

const bucketName = 'marketown-products';
try {
    const imageData = req.body;
    // Key
    const key = 'image_' + new Date().getTime();

    const params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: key,
        Body: imageData,
    };

    const command = new PutObjectCommand(params);
    await s3Client.send(command);
    res.status(200).json({ key: key });
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error uploading image to S3:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Unable to upload image to S3' });
    }
  }

  export default handler
```

Here is my front end logic:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function Test() {
const [file, setFile] = useState<File | null>(null);

const handleFileChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (e.target.files && e.target.files.length > 0) {
    setFile(e.target.files[0]);
    }
};

const uploadFile = async () => {
    if (file) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', file);
    console.log(formData)
    try {
        const response = await axios.post('/api/upload', formData, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
        });

        const imageUrl = response.data.key; 
        console.log('Image URL:', imageUrl);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error uploading image:', error);
    }
    }
};

return (
    <div>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <form>
        <input
        type="file"
        accept="image/*"
        name="image"
        id="selectFile"
        onChange={handleFileChange}
        />
        <button type="button" onClick={uploadFile}>
        Upload
        </button>
    </form>
    </div>
 );
 }

 export default Test;
```

Comment: "but when I downloaded it, it is not an image" can you provide details about your desired and actual behavior?

Comment: It was supposed to be stored as an image like png and jpeg, but when i downloaded the image, it was not png, jpeg or another image format

Comment: What if you add `ContentType: "image/image__type"` on s3 put_obj_cmd params?